# HornetQ REST interface not working

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I was following the [guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.beta1/docs/rest-manual/html/ch04.html) to enable REST interface in the HornetQ broker running inside the Jboss EAP 6.1. No matter what I do I keep getting this error and the page shows

```
Queue 'testQueue' does not exist
```

I'm running standalone Jboss EAP 6.1 using standalone-full.xml
I created a single 'testQueue' queue.
I tried upgrading versions of the jboss-rest jar to newer version - nothing works. Has anyone had similar problems? what was your solution? (upgrading Jboss to the newer version is not an option at this moment).

```
10:00:20,367 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8080-1) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationExce
ption
        at org.hornetq.rest.queue.QueueDestinationsResource.findQueue(QueueDestinationsResource.java:159) [hornetq-rest-2.3.1.Final.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.createResource(ResourceLocator.java:65) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat
-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.createResource(ResourceLocator.java:54) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat
-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocator.invoke(ResourceLocator.java:91) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Fi
nal-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-r
edhat-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.
jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Fin
al-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:59) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.
6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.
Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-re
dhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1
]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1
]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat
-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.F
inal-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the way I was accessing the queue. I had to prepend 'jms.queue.' to the name of my queue: jms.queue.testQueue. I was able to access the queue after that.